# Additivity property of conditional expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$.

Since $P[X\in A|Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, there exists a measurable $\phi_A:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi_A\circ Y= P[X\in A|Y]$.

When $A_1,...,A_n$ are mutually disjoint, how do I prove that $\phi_{\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi_{A_i}$ $Y_*P$-a.e.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any measurable set $E$ we have $$\int_{Y^{-1}(E)} \phi_{\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i}\circ Y dP=P(X \in \cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i, Y \in E)$$ $$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X \in A_i, Y \in E)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{Y^{-1}(E)} \phi_{A_i}\circ Y dP.$$ We can write this as $\int_E \phi_{\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i} dP\circ Y^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_E \phi_{A_i} dP\circ Y^{-1}$. This is true for all $E$.  Hence $\phi_{\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi_{A_i}$ w.r.t the measure $P\circ Y^{-1}$ induced by $Y$.

Comment: Aha! Amazing. Thank you!