# Limit under the push-forward measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

(This question is very similar to this one: [Additivity property of conditional expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3282638/44669))

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $Y:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a measurable function.

Let $\phi_n,\phi:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable functions such that $\phi_n,\phi$ are of $L^1(Y_*P)$.

If $\phi_n \circ Y \to \phi\circ Y$ almost surely with respect to $P$ and $0\leq \phi_n \circ Y \leq \phi_{n+1}\circ Y$ ($P$-a.e.), then $\phi_n \to \phi$ almost surely with respect ro $Y_*P$?

It is obvious that $ \int_B \phi_n d(Y_*P) \to \int_B \phi d(Y_*P)$ for every $B\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^m}$, but I do not know how to proceed next..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E=\{x\in\mathbb R^m\colon \lim_n\phi_n(x)\not=\phi(x)\}$. We wish to show that $Y_*P(E)=0$. By definition of the [pushforward of a measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure),
$$
Y_*P(E)=P\bigl(Y^{-1}(E)\bigr).
$$
Also by definition,
$$
Y^{-1}(E)=\{\omega\in\Omega\colon Y(\omega)\in E\}.
$$
By definition of $E$, we have that $Y(\omega)\in E$ if and only if $\lim_n\phi_n(Y(\omega))\not=\phi(Y(\omega))$, and thus
$$
Y^{-1}(E)=\bigl\{\omega\in\Omega\colon \lim_n\phi_n\circ Y(\omega)\not=\phi\circ Y(\omega)\bigr\}.
$$
By hypothesis, this set is $P$-null, and therefore $P(Y^{-1}(E))=0$, as desired.

---

Our argument is showing more generally (without any hypotheses) that
$$P\bigl(\lim_n\phi_n\circ Y\not= \phi\circ Y\bigr)=Y_*P\bigl(\lim_n\phi_n\not=\phi\bigr).$$
In particular, one side is $0$ if and only if the other side is $0$. (This answers your question more succinctly.)

Comment: Note that most of the assumptions mentioned in the question aren't even needed.

Comment: Correct, what my post is showing is that (by definition) the following two statements are equivalent: 1. $\phi_n\circ Y\to \phi\circ Y$ a.s.-$P$, and 2. $\phi_n\to\phi$ a.s.-$Y_*P$

Comment: Aha. Silly me. Thank you!